# Functional way to create and populate arrays in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming

How can I create and populate the array in a functional way than the following imperative way?

### Imperative Code

```
IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

// my input data is array of strings

string[] ids = {"4", "6"};
string[] names = {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"};

for (var i = 0; i<ids.Length; i++) 
{
    customers.Add(new Customer
    { 
         Id = Int32.Parse(ids[i]),
         Name = names[i],
    });
}
```

### Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what are the desired results?

Comment: Indeed, what does `functional way` mean here? `Zip` or `Zip().ToArray()` look more "functional" but they still generate and modify arrays - possibly many arrays due to buffer reallocation. `Zip()` alone is a `functional` way, as it produces a sequence of the desired items instead of a sequence. That sequence can be consumed by other functions that expect such a sequence, especially LINQ functions

Comment: BTW `List<T>` isn't an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `functional` you mean without loops, you can use LINQ's `Zip` to combine values and produce an `IEnmerable<Customer>` :

```
var customers=ids.Zip(names,(id,name)=> new Customer
                     { 
                         Id = Int32.Parse(ids[i]);
                         Name = names[i];
                     })
                 .ToArray();
                 //Or .ToList(); if a List<T> is preferable
```

I say `if` because creating the array still requires allocating an array and modifying it.It's actually *more* expensive thatn creating an array in advance because `ToArray()` doesn't know how big an array to create, so it may need to reallocate its internal buffers.

A more functional approach would be to consume the `IEnumerable<Customer>` produced by `Zip`. That sequence of customer objects can be consumed by any other LINQ operator or custom methods that expect an `IEnumerable<T>`.

A more performant version would create the array in advance and copy the values from the IEnumerable produced by zip :

```
var customers=new Customer[ids.Length];

var values=ids.Zip(names,(id,name)=> new Customer
                                     { 
                                         Id = Int32.Parse(ids[i]);
                                         Name = names[i];
                                     });
var i=0;
foreach(var values)
{
    customers[i++]=v;
}
```

Comment: I think most of this answer falls firmly into the realm of micro-optimizations. Please don't go to this level of effort unless you've got a performance issue, and your profiler has told you that `ToList()` / `ToArray()` is the problem.

Comment: @canton7 on the contrary, asking about *functional* is a micro-optimization - what are we trying to gain here. As for reallocations, it's a well know problem with quite a few (as in several dozens) SO questions asking why `.Add` or `ToList` results in OOM exceptions. In fact, `List<T>` is implemented the way it is because the *reallocations* are far faster than a linked list for example.

Comment: @canton7 besides, `Zip` is a bit of a functional cheat here. It uses a loop itself. Perhaps the OP wants a recursive method? That would actually be slower and require lots of copies

Comment: The question has nothing to do with performance, so not sure why you interpret the question as being about micro-optimization? The whole definition of a micro-optimization is that it's something that you shouldn't do *unless* it turns out to be a problem. `ToList()` causing an OOM is a problem, but it won't do that with reasonable amounts of data. Most of .NET's functional stuff is implemented using loops, and I don't think anyone would argument that that makes it non-functional

Comment: The first part of your answer is good, but I do think that going straight into talking about avoiding the use of `ToList()` without explaining that this *shouldn't* be done in most cases is misleading. I wanted to make this clear to the OP, in case they picked up a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
customers = ids.Zip(names, (id, name) => new Customer { Id = Int32.Parse(id), Name = name }).ToList();
```